# PHP request name from textbox with same name

Tags: php, html

I have multiple textbox with same name, example :

```
<input type = "text" name = "addCart"/> 
<input type = "text" name = "addCart"/>
<input type = "text" name = "addCart"/>
<input type = "text" name = "addCart"/>
```

If I  do a $_Request from php and I want to get the value inputted only from the first and fourth textbox, how can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  The last input box's value will overwrite all of the other ones' since they have the same name.

What you could consider doing is using `name="addCart[]"`

Then, $_REQUEST['addCart'] would be an array.

Like:

```
<input type="text" name="addCart[]" value="a">
<input type="text" name="addCart[]" value="b">
```

Then $_REQUEST['addCart'] (or $_POST or $_GET whichever you're using) would contain an array of two strings 'a' and 'b'.

Edit:  Just for completeness, I should note that this array is a normal array.  Thus $_REQUEST['addCart'][x] where x is some integer index is valid as long as count($_REQUEST['addCart']) > x.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type = "text" name = "addCart[]"/> 
<input type = "text" name = "addCart[]"/>
<input type = "text" name = "addCart[]"/>
<input type = "text" name = "addCart[]"/>
```

Access using:

```
$_REQUEST['addCart'][0]
...
$_REQUEST['addCart'][3]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, this will post the array of addCart. With $_REQUEST you can acces teh first and fourth texhbox by addCart id

```
<input type = "text" name = "addCart[]"/> 
<input type = "text" name = "addCart[]"/>
<input type = "text" name = "addCart[]"/>
<input type = "text" name = "addCart[]"/>


<?php
echo $_REQUEST['addCart'][0];
echo $_REQUEST['addCart'][3];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use names of that style when using PHP, then you have to bypass `$_POST` or `$_GET`, get the raw data and parse it yourself.

For GET requests, then means looking at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and for POST at `file_get_contents('php://input');`

If you rename the fields so the names end in `[]` then they will be presented as an array.

i.e.

```
<input type = "text" name = "addCart[]"/>
```

Will be presented as

```
$_GET['addCart'][] or $_POST['addCart'][]
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe this is possible. try to use slightly different names such as name1, name2 etc